# Tank Game: Can't figure out the right formule for enemy aiming

Tags: flash

Recently I've been watching Flash video: "Lynda.com - ActionScript 3.0 Projects: Game Development" with Todd Perkins.

Last lesson was "creating a Flash Tank Game". I was following along and created the exact same game that was described in the lesson.

But in the lesson's example enemy tank had no descent AI. Enemy was moving and shooting randomly, and it didn't seem to be a lot fun playing this game.

I've decided to make AI to be more enhanced. I've managed to make enemy change direction of movement if it was hit by player.

If an enemy successfully hits the player it stops and continues to shoot player with the same gun angle and same position until he missed or got hit by player.

The problem is that formula for calculating right gun angle isn't correct enough. Enemy kind of shoots right, but he still misses a lot.

So, here is the formula that I've used:

```
enemyTargetRotation=Math.asin(Math.abs(enemy_mc.y - player_mc.y)/(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(player_mc.x - enemy_mc.x, 2)+ Math.pow((enemyWall_mc.height - stage.height),2)))/180*Math.PI);
      enemyTargetRotation*=10000;
      enemyTargetRotation+=180;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) / Math.PI * 180`? It should give shooting angle in degrees given x1,y1 coordinates of tank and x2,y2 coordinates of target.

Comment: Um, the problem is that enemy Tank is standing on a high ground. And bullet that tanks are firing don't follow a straight line, it's following a parabola. You can check source code to verify  http://www.megaupload.com/?d=CH48PEML

Comment: Ну тогда надо уравнение параболы решать. Угол - неизвестная, начало в своем танке, должна пересекать чужой. http://ido.tsu.ru/schools/physmat/data/res/virtlab/text/m2_1.html

Comment: ээээ... но там в уравнении параболы, что-то типа y=x*tg(a) - x^2/(2*v^2-cos^2(a))... Так вот нужный угол а и под тангенсом и под косинусом как его найти? я не очень силён в тригонометрии... надо как-то из тангенса получить косинус?

Comment: Так... tg(x)=sin(x)/cos(x), но там во второй части cos^2(x). А cos^2(x)=1/2 + 1/2*cos(2x). пытался решить, но там получилось какое-то моструозное выражение. Я понял, что я не знаю как сократить cos(2x)/cos(x). и это точно не cos(x) :)) В общем я в тупике.

Comment: я сам не спец по этим косинусам, но любое уравнение можно решить численным методом - найти угол недолета и перелета, а потом делить их пополам, пока не попадешь. За несколько итераций должно сойтись.